# R - Getting incorrect results for matrix mulitplication on a column from a list

Tags: r

I am processing list data data that I am doing matrix calculations on and I am getting some strange behavior.

When I pull the data from the list and apply the tcrossprod function I get different answers than I would expect. Below is a simplified example of the issue.

My data is of this form...

```
> test_list <- list(data.frame("col1" = c('a','b'), "col2" = c(229187.82,135323.01)))

> test_list
[[1]]
  col1   col2
1    a 229188
2    b 135323
```

Applying tcrossprod gives an incorrect result on the data...

```
> tcrossprod(test_list[[1]]$col2)
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 52527056836 31014385658
[2,] 31014385658 18312317035
```

This is the correct answer...

```
> vec <- c(229188,135323)

> vec
[1] 229188 135323

> tcrossprod(vec)
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 52527139344 31014407724
[2,] 31014407724 18312314329
```

And here is the difference between the two calculations...

```
> tcrossprod(vec) - tcrossprod(test_list[[1]]$col2)
        [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 82507.6 22066.26
[2,] 22066.3 -2706.46
```

I can't find a reason why there is a discrepancy between the two calculations...

```
> typeof(test_list[[1]]$col2)
[1] "double"
> typeof(vec)
[1] "double"

> class(test_list[[1]]$col2)
[1] "numeric"
> class(vec)
[1] "numeric"
```

Is there a way to fix this issue so the numbers calculated are correct?

Comment: You're using different numbers as inputs. If `vec <- c(229187.82,135323.01)` then `tcrossprod(test_list[[1]]$col2) - tcrossprod(vec)` is zero.

Comment: Maybe you want `tcrossprod(round(test_list[[1]]$col2))`, since your sample `vec` seems to be rounded to the nearest integer?

Comment: That was dumb of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the real value in your dataframe is c(229187.82,135323.01).
Then when you display they round it to: c(229188,135323)

In your example you then use the rounded numbers which are not the right ones.

```
> test_list <- list(data.frame("col1" = c('a','b'), "col2" = c(229187.82,135323.01)))
> a<-test_list[[1]]$col2
> vec1 <- matrix(c(229187.82,135323.01),nrow=2)
> tcrossprod(vec1)
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 52527056836 31014385658
[2,] 31014385658 18312317035
> vec2=matrix(a,nrow=2)
> tcrossprod(vec2)
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 52527056836 31014385658
[2,] 31014385658 18312317035
```